# Move Character Tile by Tile

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a 2D game. I got a character and some tiles. The tiles are 1 x 1 unit, and placed in scene.

I used the following codes to move my character. Here is my character ("Hero")'s code:

```
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector2 speedX = new Vector2(1, 0);
    private Vector2 speedY = new Vector2(0, 1);

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey("left")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position - speedX * Time.deltaTime);
        } else if(Input.GetKey("right")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + speedX * Time.deltaTime);
        } else if(Input.GetKey("up")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + speedY * Time.deltaTime);
        } else if(Input.GetKey("down")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position - speedY * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it does not move as expected. It moves around 0.2 units when I press the arrow key once. How can I make the player moves 1 unit per key down ?

What did I miss?

Documentation: [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)

Comment: Why do you use RigidBody2D? Are you going to use any physics in the game?

Comment: I need collision detection in game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see, it looks like you want to achieve instant movement of character to new position once key is pressed. If so, you have two errors here:

1. You don't need to multiply speed (`speedX` or `speedY`) by `Time.deltaTime`.
2. `Input.GetKey` is not what you want to use, because it will return true in every frame where key is pressed (not once per key pressing). Instead, you need to use `Input.GetKeyDown`.

So, your code should look like this:

```
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector2 speedX = new Vector2(1, 0);
    private Vector2 speedY = new Vector2(0, 1);

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("left")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position - speedX);
        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown("right")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + speedX);
        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown("up")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + speedY);
        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown("down")) {
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position - speedY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm ! Unity 3D documentation guides me to a wrong way.